# Facebook SDK integration with sencha touch, redirect url for app made in sencha

Tags: javascript, facebook, extjs, sencha-touch-2.2

While integrating facebook login and other features of it using its SDK for javascript for developing a native app for android, the problem faced is of redirect uri means for PC testing. Localhost is given but when the app is deployed on mobile it is just not loading and giving an error with a url mentioning an in app setting is not valid or something. As I am not hosting the app like on heroku or other, I am making it strictly for android using javascript and html5. What is the appropriate url for this to run on a mobile phone.

Comment: Can you give the actual error message and what request you are making?

Comment: The error is speciaficaly beacause of redirect url is demanding for domain name and since the app is not hosted ,it is like other android native app which only needs authentication from facebook. More precisely how to deploy sencha app on mobile (app not hosted on web) integrated with facebook